# How to properly add two conditions to mongodb find()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Having trouble with finding data. I have to conditions:
1. Matching ID
2. Time range

It works fine when use find() only by id, but there is a polling error when I try to use both or only time.Here what I have so far:

```
findRange: function (dateRange, callback) {
    ExpenseModel.find(
            {telegramId: dateRange.telegramId,
            time:{
                    $gt: ISODate(dateRange.from),
                    $lte: ISODate(dateRange.to)
            }},
            function (err, existingSequence) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                    return;
                }
                if (existingSequence) {
                    callback(null, existingSequence);
                } else {
                    console.log("not found")
                    callback(null, false);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$and` property

```
findRange: function (dateRange, callback) {
    ExpenseModel.find({$and : [
                 { telegramId: dateRange.telegramId},
                 { time:{
                    $gt: ISODate(dateRange.from),
                    $lte: ISODate(dateRange.to)
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
            function (err, existingSequence) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                    return;
                }
                if (existingSequence) {
                    callback(null, existingSequence);
                } else {
                    console.log("not found")
                    callback(null, false);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```